# How to use findstr within a loop?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, findstr

I am trying to read the filename and according to the filename set the `Output` variable.

I have tried using `findstr` directly on `%%F (findstr /i "M002" %%F >nul 2>&1 )` and also writing to a temp text file (as below) to test and read it, but nothing worked.

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. If I remove this out from the loop the code works, but I need it within the loop due to the last line.

```
rem ===========================================

set FileType=pdf

for %%F in (%~dp0*.%FileType%) do (
  rem ECHO %%F

  echo "%%F" > test.txt
  findstr /i "M002" test.txt >nul 2>&1
  echo %errorlevel%
  if not %errorlevel% == 0 (
      echo "4pp"
      echo %%F
      set Output=4PP
  ) ELSE (
      echo "Letter"
      echo %%F
      set Output=Letter
  )

  set NetComm="XYZ" "%Output%" etc etc etc
)

rem ====================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Generation 5,961 of `delayedexpansion`.

Batch parses the entire statement from the `for` through to the last closing parenthesis and replaces **any** `%var%` with the value of that variable **at the time the statement is parsed**.

Consequently, attempting to use a value which is established within the loop will fail. This applies to `%output%` and `%errorlevel%` in the current instance.

Dealing with `%errorlevel%` is easy. The syntax

```
if errorlevel n
```

works on the **run-time** value of `errorlevel` and is true if `errorlevel` has been set to `n` or **greater** than `n`.

Personally, I find the `if not condition ... else` clumsy. I can't see why it's so common. Fuzzy thinking in my book...

There are three common ways to overcome the problem, each has its own advantages and disadvantages, proponents and critics.

First, the "documented" method. Use a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` instruction. Once this instruction has been executed, `!var!` will access the **current** value and `%var%` the **initial**`value of`var`.

Second, the subroutine method. `CALL :sub` within a loop executes a subroutine (see the documentation - `call /?` from the prompt) and within that subroutine, `%var%` will have the value as established within the loop.

Third, it's sometimes possible to use `call echo %%var%%` (or `call someotherinsruction`) where the `call` is executiong the target as if it was a subroutine.

Hence, in your case, a fix might be

```
rem ===========================================

set FileType=pdf

for %%F in (%~dp0*.%FileType%) do (
  rem ECHO %%F

  findstr /i "M002" "%%F" >nul 2>nul
  CALL echo %%errorlevel%%
  if errorlevel 1 (
      echo "4pp"
      echo %%F
      set Output=4PP
  ) ELSE (
      echo "Letter"
      echo %%F
      set Output=Letter
  )

  CALL set NetComm="XYZ" "%%Output%%" etc etc etc
)

rem ====================================
```

depending entirely on your definition of "works" (which is not an absolute - it has meaning only to you.)

Comment: Fine and dandy. If you'd care to press the tick, that'll assign points and show the problem as being solved.